# stellar-core can be controlled via the commands (No config file FILE found)

Tags: stellar-core

following [this link](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/commands.html)!.

When specifying a config file to use.

```
stellar-core --conf FILE default 'stellar-core.cfg'
```

I get

```
error : 2018-11-17T11:25:32.680 <startup> [default FATAL] 
Got an exception: No config file FILE found [main.cpp:943]
```

Comment: in ubntu i find it in .

/etc /stellar-core/stellar-core.cfg

Answer (score 1):

I think you're supposed to only provide the file path without the "FILE default".

Have you tried using the absolute path? If your stellar-core.cfg is in /somewhere/stellar-core.cfg try using the full path.

Just using the file name will force stellar-core to look in the directory where it was installed to and your file probably is not located there.